# Hugging Face Trainer: Error in the model init

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am getting the following error:

```
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run_hyperparameter_search.py", line 74, in <module>
    trainer = Trainer(
  File "/ext3/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 273, in __init__
    model = self.call_model_init()
  File "/ext3/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 737, in call_model_init
    raise RuntimeError("model_init should have 0 or 1 argument.")
RuntimeError: model_init should have 0 or 1 argument.
~
```

Here is what I call in my hugging face trainer:

```
#Initialising the model
trainer = Trainer(
    args = training_args,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,
    train_dataset = train_data,
    eval_dataset = val_data,
    # maybe there is a () in the init, but not in compute metrics for sure. Will test
    model_init = finetuning_utils.model_init(),
    compute_metrics = finetuning_utils.compute_metrics,
)
```

The problem is apparently in the model_init.

Here is what the finetuning_utils.model_init() encompasses:

```
def model_init():
    """Returns an initialized model for use in a Hugging Face Trainer."""
    ## TODO: Return a pretrained RoBERTa model for sequence classification.
    ## See https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html#robertaforsequenceclassification.
    model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
    #model = model.to('cuda')
    return model
```

Please help with the error.

Comment: From https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/trainer.html it looks like model_init takes a callable. Have you tried removing the parentheses i.e. just `finetuning_utils.model_init` ?

Comment: Or perhaps using `model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base")` instead of `model_init`

Comment: @ML_Engine Thank you!

Comment: I've added it as an answer, would appreciate an 'accept' if it helped :-)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Huggingface trainer docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/trainer.html) it looks like `model_init` takes a callable. So rather than instantiating the parameter it should take the callable itself i.e. without parenthesis:

```
model_init = finetuning_utils.model_init
```

Alternatively you could remove `model_init` and use the `model` parameter to the same effect as the code contained within `finetuning_utils.model_init` like so:

```
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
```